# Create several XML files from one

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a single XML file that is formatted like this:

```
<Main1>
  <Sub1>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Sub2>
      <Prop>
        <Key>A</Key>
        <Value>Apple</Value>
      </Prop>
      <Prop>
        <Key>B</Key>
        <Value>Ball</Value>
      </Prop>
    </Sub2>
    <Sub3>
      <Order>
        <OID>54321</OID>
        <ODate>2016-01-01</ODate>
      </Order>
    </Sub3>
  </Sub1>
</Main1>
```

I am trying to have python import this xml and split it into three different files: a file for the persons name and id, a file for the properties, and a file for the order information. However, as I split it, I want to add the customer id to the property and order file. So the property file may end up looking like:

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <OID>54321</OID>
    <ODate>2016-01-01</ODate>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

Comment: XML only allows a single root node in a document - so how would the property file look, since there seem to be several `<Prop />` nodes?

Comment: I apologize for that. The root would be "Orders" with each "Order" being a different node.

Comment: And the same for `<Properties>` I assume?

Comment: You could loop through line by line, find the lines that contain the values you want and write those values to the appropriate files

Comment: @Lucas Graf -- That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and [`element.xpath()`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) to select the nodes you need, and append them to nodes in new XML documents as you need.

[XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is not a concept introduced by `lxml` but a general query language for selecting nodes from an XML document supported by many things that deal with XML. Think of it as something similar to CSS selectors, but more powerful (also a bit more complicated). See [**XPath Syntax**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

So, for example,

```
tree.xpath('/Main1/Sub1')
```

would select the `<Sub1 />` element directly below the `<Main1 />` node.

Notice that `.xpath()` always returns a list of selected nodes - so if you want just one, account for that.

So, something like this should work:

```
from copy import copy
from lxml import etree


def parse(filename):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    root = etree.parse(open(filename), parser=parser)
    return root


def dump_to_file(root, filename_base, id_):
    customer_id = id_.text.strip()
    filename = '%s-%s.xml' % (filename_base, customer_id)
    with open(filename, 'w') as xml_file:
        etree.ElementTree(root).write(xml_file, pretty_print=True)


def dump_orders(id_, orders):
    root = etree.XML('<Orders/>')
    for order in orders:
        order.append(copy(id_))
        root.append(order)
    dump_to_file(root, 'orders', id_)


def dump_properties(id_, properties):
    root = etree.XML('<Properties/>')
    for prop in properties:
        prop.append(copy(id_))
        root.append(prop)
    dump_to_file(root, 'properties', id_)


def dump_customer(id_, name):
    root = etree.XML('<Customer/>')
    root.append(copy(id_))
    root.append(copy(name))
    dump_to_file(root, 'customer', id_)


root = parse('complete.xml')
customers = root.xpath('/Main1/Sub1')

for customer in customers:
    name = customer.xpath('./Name')[0]
    id_ = customer.xpath('./ID')[0]
    dump_customer(id_, name)

    properties = customer.xpath('./Sub2/Prop')
    dump_properties(id_, properties)

    orders = customer.xpath('./Sub3/Order')
    dump_orders(id_, orders)
```

---

This will create three files like this per customer:

**`customer-12345.xml`**

```
<Customer>
  <ID>12345</ID>
  <Name>Test</Name>
</Customer>
```

**`orders-12345.xml`**

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OID>54321</OID>
    <ODate>2016-01-01</ODate>
    <ID>12345</ID>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

**`properties-12345.xml`**

```
<Properties>
  <Prop>
    <Key>A</Key>
    <Value>Apple</Value>
    <ID>12345</ID>
  </Prop>
  <Prop>
    <Key>B</Key>
    <Value>Ball</Value>
    <ID>12345</ID>
  </Prop>
</Properties>
```

For more information on the XPath syntax, see for example the [**XPath Syntax**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) page in the [W3Schools Xpath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

To get going with XPath it can also be very helpful to fiddle around with your document in one of the many [**XPath testers**](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm).

Comment: This will definitely get me to where we need to be.